# compilation of derived class with no implementation of pure virtual function does not give any errors

Tags: c++

I have read that a pure virtual functions are the virtual functions whose implementation must be provided by the derived class and I wanted to test it. Do do so I derived a class from an abstract class which has a pure virtual member function. For the educational purpose I did not implement this function in the derived class, just to see whether it breaks. To my surprise the code compiled with no problems.

I would like to ask you to help me to understand why my code does compile with no implementation of the pure virtual function in the derived class. 
I would be very happy to any hint that would help me to understand that.

```
├── AbstractClass.cpp
├── AbstractClass.h
├── cmake-build-debug
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── DerivedClass.cpp
├── DerivedClass.h
└── main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DerivedClass.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

AbstractClass.h

```
#ifndef TUTORIAL_CLASSES_ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#define TUTORIAL_CLASSES_ABSTRACTCLASS_H


class AbstractClass {
public:
    virtual int& pure_virtual_function(int) = 0;
    virtual int const_member_function() const = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractClass() {};

};


#endif //TUTORIAL_CLASSES_ABSTRACTCLASS_H
```

AbstractCLass.cpp

```
#include "AbstractClass.h"
```

DerivedClass.h

```
#ifndef TUTORIAL_CLASSES_DERIVEDCLASS_H
#define TUTORIAL_CLASSES_DERIVEDCLASS_H

#include "AbstractClass.h"

    class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass{
    public:
        DerivedClass() {};
    };


    #endif //TUTORIAL_CLASSES_DERIVEDCLASS_H
```

DerivedClass.cpp

```
#include "DerivedClass.h"

X555LJ:~/CLionProjects/tutorial_classes/cmake-build-debug$ make
[100%] Built target tutorial_classes
```

Comment: A derived class can also be abstract (not only top level classes can). If you try to create an instance of the derived (but still abstract) class you should get an error.

Comment: Thank you both! It was very unwise from my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From cppreference [abstract class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class):

> An abstract class is a class that either defines or inherits at least one function for which the final overrider is pure virtual.

You haven't tried to create instance of it so it works as expected - DerivedClass is abstract as well.